# TMS3615NS Datasheet

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, datasheet

I've got a tMS3615NS which should be an octave multiple tone synthesizer (dip28), I've found only a datasheet online, but the pinout is missing.
Has anyone a copy about this component or knows a general rule for this kind of IC?
Thanks.

P.S. this IC is dated 41th week of 1984

Comment: Perhaps this one : https://www.narcisivalter.it/progetti/PDFs/TMS3615NS_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help